# Is QGIS 1.8 available for Ubuntu?

Tags: qgis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install QGIS on Ubuntu 12.04?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29094/how-to-install-qgis-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Title says it all, and if so, how do I go about getting it? I currently have 1.7 Wroclaw installed via the Ubuntu Software Center, but I need the more advanced Field Calculator of 1.8.

I am using Ubuntu out of necessity because the Windows version has a bug preventing large raster images being exported. I'm unfamiliar with all the ridiculous hoop-jumping and command typing seemingly required to simply install software in Ubuntu, so answer as if to a complete idiot and you won't be far off the truth!

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following commands in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install add-apt-repository
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis
```

However i would recommend to use the official QGIS sources. More information [here](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#26-Ubuntu)