# Geting and installing latest version of QGIS in Ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu

I'd like to get the latest 64-bit dev build of QGIS on my Ubuntu setup.

How exactly do I go about it?

I assume it's some kind of arcane terminal command.

Comment: Please Check out http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29094/how-to-install-qgis-on-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to add the ppa of ubuntugis first.

From commandline:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable 
sudo apt-get update
```

the add the following line to the file /etc/apt/sources.list (you can also use the sofware center for that)

```
deb     http://qgis.org/debian-nightly precise main
```

then install qgis

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis
```

Comment: I get this:The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 qgis : Depends: libgdal1-1.7.0 but it is not installable
        Depends: libqgis1.9.0 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: qgis-providers (= 1.9.0+git20130114+bdcb6c1~precise1) but 1.8.0-1~quantal3 is to be installed
        Recommends: qgis-plugin-globe but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: qgis-plugin-grass but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: I have done a sudo apt-get dist-upgrade and now it reports 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 not upgraded, but still get the error message when trying to install qgis.

Comment: Solved - I had to completely remove the old QGIS installations and all it's various bits around the system (using Synaptic Package Manager), then set the only QGIS repositories to the ones above.