# Will core functions in QGIS exploit multi-threading?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, multithreading, qgis-3

After reading [Enabling multithreaded processing in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98335), I was wondering if QGIS 2.6 will include this when running various processes. I checked online and I could only find that **multi-threaded rendering** was introduced to QGIS 2.4 (I assume it will again be available in 2.6). Now maps can be redrawn very quickly especially when dealing with large datasets.

I read that it's fairly difficult to include multi-threading to core functionality and that users are advised to manipulate Python code in order to achieve this, such as in [Parallelising GIS operations in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119961).

I also checked the [feature request](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/2037) but it has been closed for 9 months now by Tim Sutton with the last comment being:

> "I'm closing this out - Martin Dobias has an implementation in a branch which will be merged post QGIS 2.2"

Will some functions in QGIS 2.6 exploit multi-threading (or will it again be focused on rendering) and if not, will that change at QGIS 3.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the answer for QGIS 3.0 may be found in this recent conversation posted in [Nabble](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/):

[Will Processing in QGIS 3 support parallelization?](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Will-Processing-in-QGIS-3-support-parallelization-td5301809.html)

Citing Nyall Dawson:

> If you're after parallelization *within* a single algorithm (Eg 
>   buffering features using multiple threads) then I'm unaware of any 
>   plans in place to handle this.

Answer (score 4):

Rendering only at this current time (QGIS 2.6).

Martin and I have talked about some kind of generic threaded process API but it's just talks at this current time.