# Does CPU with more cores help for lesser rendering time in QGIS 2.18?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

In the settings, there is an option to check to use multicores.
Would this mean the more cores we have, the faster rendering we get?

Answer (score 6):

Multithreaded rendering does help in the case where you have multiple layers to draw. QGIS will dedicate one core per layer for rendering.

If you have more cores in your machine than layers on your map canvas, that will give no significant performance gain.

Sidenote, that at the moment there is a lot of work put into more background tasking. This will be available in QGIS 3.0, the framework for this has already been added. It can be expected, that more parts of QGIS will be able to use your cores in parallel in the near future (the most obvious candidate being processing algorithms).

Comment: Looking very much forward to the framework addition as I have been waiting [for over two years now](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120185/will-core-functions-in-qgis-2-6-exploit-multi-threading) ;)

Comment: "one core per layer" : This kind of answers it all. Thank you.