# Is QGIS multi-threaded?

Tags: qgis, multithreading

Is QGIS (2.16) multi-threaded?

I do not see multiple processes on the console while running it on Ubuntu.

It only uses one CPU.

Is there anything to do to enable it?

Comment: NOT a duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rendering can use multiple cores:

[image]

Most processing/analyses are still single-threaded but devs are working on it, see [Enabling multithreaded processing in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98335/how-to-enable-multithreaded-processing-in-qgis-2-2?rq=1)