# How to install QGIS with OpenGeo Suite on Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, boundless-suite

I was wondering how should one install QGIS after installing OpenGeo Suite on Ubuntu Linux?

I installed OpenGeo 4.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 following the instructions on the official website http://suite.opengeo.org/4.1/installation/ubuntu/install.html, which involves adding the OpenGeo repository

```
echo "deb http://apt.opengeo.org/suite/v4/ubuntu/ precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opengeo.list
```

I installed QGIS following [this GIS.SE answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29211/34474), which involved adding

```
"deb http://qgis.org/debian precise main"
```

Both packages seem to be functioning. But there seems to be a conflict in the Ubuntu's repository system after installing these two. When I tried to `apt-get install curl`, I was told that there is a conflict, and I need to use 'apt-get -f install'.

I had to restore my OS to the previous state without QGIS.

I also tried to `apt-get install qgis` after installing opengeo, without adding the qgis.org repository, and I got an error like this:

```
Package qgis is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'qgis' has no installation candidate
```

My question is, what's the proper way to install QGIS and OpenGeo together?

-- Update --

I have tried to download boundless's version of GIS, as suggested in one of the answers. But their package are for windows and mac only. No Linux version is provided.

Answer (score 2):

I've had mixed results with Boundless repositories. If you stick to their products it all works, but as soon as you try to upgrade versions of GDAL, or install other things like QGIS, you run into issues.

I would suggest that you keep your use cases separate, and install the OpenGeoSuite on a server and QGIS on your desktop. If you're really keen on getting the OGS on your machine, think about using Docker to simplify it and keep it separate from your main operating system (and it looks like someone has already done it: https://hub.docker.com/r/mkzaker/opengeo-suite/).

Also, keep in mind that you could just install native GeoServer, depending on your needs, and the GeoServer Admin plugin for QGIS. I no longer see a huge amount of value in the Boundless package, though GeoExplorer is a very handy tool for doing styling. (I should say that I do see value in Boundless for support and associated services! It's just that I use vanilla GeoServer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the two things are different and independent since I don't find any qgis packages or library in [this independecies section](http://suite.opengeo.org/4.1/installation/ubuntu/packages.html#installation-ubuntu-packages).

This said, I really don't know what happened to your system but I think that Qgis and OpenGeo Suite should be installed, as a fresh installation,following these step:

1. Install Qgis as suggested from Giovanni Manghi [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29094/how-to-install-qgis-on-ubuntu-12-04?lq=1) - ([ubuntugis repository](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable))
2. Install OpenGeo Suite 4.1 as described [here](http://suite.opengeo.org/4.1/installation/ubuntu/install.html). If I well understood "Opengeo Qgis plugin" is part of the installation.

After that you'd be able to open Qgis, but perhaps you will have to enable the plug in.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://boundlessgeo.com/solutions/solutions-software/qgis/qgis-download/,

you have to register for free to get a download link to their version of QGIS.

The Boundless Ubuntu repository has some packages that ubuntugis has too, but in a newer version. These packages might raise conflicts.

The [Boundless release notes](http://boundlessgeo.com/solutions/opengeo-suite/release-notes/) include only QGIS 2.2, so it might fail with QGIS 2.4.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I went to link and registered. I got an email with download links. However, they are for Windows and Mac only. A file for windows is: OpenGeoSuite-QGIS-windows-latest.zip

Comment: http://boundlessgeo.com/solutions/opengeo-suite/release-notes/ still mentions Ubuntu support.