# Importing qgis.core on Ubuntu Server

Tags: pyqgis, installation, ubuntu

My goal is to run QGIS processing algorithms using a python script on an ubuntu server.

I have installed QGIS on the server using

```
 $ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get install qgis
```

from [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29094/installing-qgis-on-ubuntu) to [Installing QGIS on Ubuntu](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29094).
The install was successful.

I have tried importing qgis.core but I get the module not found error.

I think I need to add some lines to the PYTHONPATH variable based on other answers. I've added the following:

```
:/usr/lib/qgis/plugins/:/usr/lib/qgis/plugins:/usr/lib/qgis:/usr/share/qgis/python:/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins:/home/wporter/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python:/home/wporter/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins:/usr/share/qgis/python:/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins:/usr/bin/qgis/share/qgis/python:/usr/share/qgis/python
```

But I'm still not able to import qgis.core.

How can I direct Python to the correct libraries on the Ubuntu server?